# why my glGetAttribLocation return 0 for position and color

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, qt5.4

I don't understand why glGetAttribLocation return 0 for my in_vertex, and in_color, instead of 0 and 1

## My shaders loader

```cpp
void Shader::charger()
{
     bool   compile_vert_ok;
     bool   compile_frag_ok;

     /* Création et compilation du vertex shader */
     _id_vertex_shader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);

     glShaderSource(_id_vertex_shader, 1, &_vertex_source, &_vertex_source_length);
     glCompileShader(_id_vertex_shader);

     compile_vert_ok = verif_compil_shader(_id_vertex_shader, "vertex");

     /* Création et compilation du fragment shader */
     _id_fragme_shader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

     glShaderSource(_id_fragme_shader, 1, &_fragme_source, &_fragme_source_length);
     glCompileShader(_id_fragme_shader);

     compile_frag_ok = verif_compil_shader(_id_fragme_shader, "fragment");

     // S'il y a un des deux shader qui n'a pas compiler correctement, on s'en va
     if( !(compile_vert_ok && compile_frag_ok))
          return;

     // On crée le programme GLSL complet qui va contenir le vertex shader et le fragment shader
     _id_shader_program = glCreateProgram();

     glAttachShader(_id_shader_program, _id_vertex_shader);
     glAttachShader(_id_shader_program, _id_fragme_shader);

     glBindAttribLocation(_id_shader_program, 0, "in_position");
     glBindAttribLocation(_id_shader_program, 1, "in_color");

     glBindFragDataLocation(_id_shader_program, 0, "out_color");

     glLinkProgram(_id_shader_program);
     if(! verif_compil_shader(_id_shader_program, "program"))
          exit(-1);

     // Spécification et envoie des variables et données au programme GLS     
     _id_position = glGetAttribLocation(_id_shader_program, "in_position");
     _id_color    = glGetAttribLocation(_id_shader_program, "in_color");

     std::cout << "\ninpos: " << _id_position;
     std::cout << "\nincol: " << _id_color << std::endl;   
}
```

my output:

```
inpos: 0
incol: 0
```

## Vertex Shader

```
#version 330 core
// Entrées

in vec3 in_position;
in vec3 in_color;

// Uniform

uniform mat4 mvp;


// Sortie

out vec3 color;


// Fonction main

void main()
{
    // Position finale du vertex en 3D

    gl_Position = mvp * ( vec4(in_position, 1.0) );


    // Envoi de la couleur au Fragment Shader

    color = in_color;
}
```

In this vertex shader, i've try to replace
"in vec3 in_position;"
by
"in vec3 layout(location=0) in_position;"

and

"in vec3 in_color;"
by
"in vec3 layout(location=1) in_color;"

and delete glBindAttribLocation instructions;

but i've same output (i.e glGetAttribLocation return 0)

## Fragment shader

```
#version 330 core
// Entrée

in vec3 color;


// Sortie 

out vec4 out_color;


// Fonction main

void main()
{
    // Couleur finale du pixel

    out_color = vec4(color, 1.0);
}
```

informations: 
[Version GLSL: 3.30]
[Version OpenGL: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 10.2.6]

i'm on Debian jessie

I use OpenGL core profile context managed by Qt5

Thanks you

Comment: The only issue I see is the line `if(! verif_compil_shader(_id_shader_program, "program"))`. I don't know what this function actually does, but checking the compile status and log for a shader is different from checking the link status of a program. However, your shaders actually should compile and link just fine, so I don't see any reson for the behavior you are getting. The problem might lie in the parts of the code you haven't pasted.

Comment: I've fix checking log for link program, with a new function "check_link_program", I check GL_LINK_PROGRAM with glGetProgramiv, and it's gl_true, so link program is fine as you said.

It's this code running firstly, i load shaders with these functions in my scene constructor